# How to link a php function with a html button?

Tags: php, html, button

I am a very beginner at php and I am having troubles. I need to call a php function, which prints a sentence on the screen, when an html button is clicked. I have writen the code below so far, but when I click the button the sentence does not appear. What's wrong with the code? Please help me! Thank you!

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['pdf'])) {
pdf();
}
?>

 <input type="button" name="pdf" value="pdf" />
<?php

function pdf(){
echo "yesssssssss";
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to put the button inside a form

Comment: use ajax you can't call php function using html button

Comment: How to do that? Can you give me a simple example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey this one is pretty straight forward. I suggest you use a form to handle that problem. The button will submit the form and call the function. 
take a look at this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    function pdf() {
        echo "yesssss";
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php
     if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
?>
        <form action="" method="post">
          <p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
          </p>      
        </form>
<?php 
     }
     else{
       pdf();
    }
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope that answers your question and helps you

Answer (score 1):

PHP is serverside script while the HTML code runs on the client.
Serverside code runs before the client can see it, then its sent to the client and rendered by the browser.
So its not possible to call php code on the page without either reloading the page or by using javascript (specifically `AJAX` or similar).

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following in your html code

```
<form name="pdf-form" method="post">

<button type="submit" name="pdf">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

html

```
<form method="post" action="yourFile.php">
<input type="submit" name="someName">
</form>
```

yourFile.php

```
if(isset($_POST['someName']){
pdf();
}
```